# Creating a Heatmap for Rooms - No Structureinfo

Tags: data-visualization, autodesk-forge

I'm working on a project in which I have to generate a heatmap for some sensors that are beeing rendered inside of a modell using forgeviewer. For the implementation I'm following this tutorial: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/examples/create_heatmap_for_rooms/

The modell I'm using was generated through Revit and translated into .svf using the Model-Derivative-API.

My problem now is, that I cant get any room or level data from my model which are needed for the generation of the heatmap.

These lines always give me no rooms or levels, eventhough there are rooms shown in the viewers modellbrowser as shown in the picture below.
[modellbrowser with rooms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AWTeN.png)

```
const structureInfo = new Autodesk.DataVisualization.Core.ModelStructureInfo(viewer.model);
        console.log("STRUCTUREINFO");
        console.log(structureInfo);
        ...
        const shadingdata= await structureInfo.generateSurfaceShadingData(devices);
        console.log("SHADINGDATA");
        console.log(shadingdata);
```

[StructureInfo in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ6ok.png)
[ShadingData in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76NF9.png)

Question now is: Why cant I get any room or level data and how can I fix this?

The only thing that came to my mind so far that I have tried was to convert the revit file into .nwd using navisworks and translating that file into .svf. But the results where the same.

Here is some more Code. Please note that the application is clientside only and wont go into production like this. I'm only creating a prototype for presentations.

```
export const initializeViewer = async (urn: string) => {
let viewer: Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D;
fetch("https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
    body: new URLSearchParams({
        client_id: "ClinetID",
        client_secret: "ClentSecret",
        grant_type: "client_credentials",
        scope: "viewables:read",
    }),
})      .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((value) => {
        const options = {
            document: urn,
            env: "AutodeskProduction",
            accessToken: value.access_token,
            api: "derivativeV2",
        };
        var container = document.getElementById("viewer-container");

        if (container !== null) {
            viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(container, {
                extensions: [],
            });
        }
        Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function onInitialized() {
            addEvents();
            viewer.start();
            Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(urn, onSuccess, onFailure);
        });
    });
    const addEvents = () => {
    viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, () => {
        loadExtensions();
        onModelLoaded(viewer);
    });
    ....
    ....
    async function onModelLoaded(viewer: Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D) {
        const dataVizExtn: any | Autodesk.Extensions.DataVisualization = await viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.DataVisualization");
    ...
    const aecModelData = await viewerDocument.downloadAecModelData();
    if (aecModelData) {
        const levelsExt: any | Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension = await viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.AEC.LevelsExtension", {
            doNotCreateUI: true,
        });
        const floorData = levelsExt.floorSelector.floorData;
        const floor = floorData[2];
        levelsExt.floorSelector.selectFloor(floor.index, true);
    }
     const structureInfo = new Autodesk.DataVisualization.Core.ModelStructureInfo(viewer.model);
    let roomDevices: Autodesk.DataVisualization.Core.RoomDevice[] = [];
    devices.forEach((device) => {
        let autodeskDevice: Autodesk.DataVisualization.Core.RoomDevice = {
            id: device.id, // An ID to identify this device
            position: device.position, // World coordinates of this device
           sensorTypes: device.sensorTypes, // The types/properties this device exposes
           type: "Thermometer",
       };
        roomDevices.push(autodeskDevice);
   });
    const heatmap = await structureInfo.generateSurfaceShadingData(roomDevices, undefined, "Rooms");
};
```

Comment: Please go to https://forge.autodesk.com/myapps to rest your client secret immediately. You just exposed it publicly...

Comment: But I didn't exose it. What you see in the code is just a placeholder and not the actual client_id and client_secret. The application wont go public like that anyway. I'm just doing it client side only at the moment for quicker programming.

Comment: You can see the editing history by clicking the blue text `edited ...` above. You posted the client id `VAUX1XlzBCQ.....lYX7PT` and the secret in the code snippet above. Please don't do that again even it's not the real one you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Looks your source model is RVT in Deutschland. If so, please use this code snippet instead.

```
const shadingdata = await structureInfo.generateSurfaceShadingData(devices, null, 'Räumen')
```

For RVT -> NWD/DWC, please check my blog post here [Add Data Visualization Heatmaps for Rooms of non-Revit model part I - NWC](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/add-data-visualization-heatmaps-rooms-non-revit-model-part-i-nwc)

Querying Revit master views in the viewer:

```js
const root = viewerDocument.getRoot();
const viewables = root.search({'type':'geometry', 'role': '3d'});

console.log('Viewables:', viewables);

const phaseViews = viewables.filter(v => v.data.name === v.data.phaseNames && v.getViewableRootPath().includes('08f99ae5-b8be-4f8d-881b-128675723c10'));

console.log('Master Views:', phaseViews);

// or this one if you just have one master view (phase) inside your model.
// viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I have updated my question for more clarification regarding my code. I also changed the model urn to now load one of autodesks example files. The rst_advanced_sample_project.rvt to be precise and I still dont get any structure informations before starting to generate a heatmap. Do I have to iterate over the levels of a model first and try to find rooms through levels?

Comment: Don't see you download the aec model data. Could you add this line before loading the DataVisualization ext? `await viewer.model.getDocumentNode().getDocument().downloadAecModelData();`

Comment: I have added the lines for the aec model data. I get levels from the model and can select a floor but I still dont get any room data which is weird because right now I#M using the technicalschoolcurrentm.rvt model, which should be the same one that is beeing used in the example.

Comment: Or is it possible, that my model somehow really doesnt have any room data? Because there are no actual rooms displayed in the model-browser as you can see in this picture: https://ibb.co/P4VvfLz

Comment: From the snapshot, I can see there is no room data inside. You need to translate the RVT model with [generateMasterViews: true](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/new-rvt-svf-model-derivative-parameter-generates-additional-content-including-rooms-and-spaces) while submitting the translation job via POST job. Afterward, you need to load the master view to see the rooms.

Comment: ok. so I already set generateMasterViews to true and also set x-ads-force in the header to true. What do you mean exactly by loading the master view? How can I do that? Because right now I'm just using the generated urn to load the translated model and that's it.

Comment: I think that I'm getting closer. In the Model Derivative Preview of the Forge-VS-Code extension are now additional Phases which contain room data. Question now is how can I switch phases in my code?

Comment: I shared a code snippet above that can help find the master view in the viewer.

Comment: Hello again. SO I managed to get the room data to show up in the Model-Browser. But I dont get the room data in my source code using `const structureInfo = new Autodesk.DataVisualization.Core.ModelStructureInfo(viewer.model);` And I have looked into the code and ModelStructureInfo always returns a null value for rooms. so do I olny get the room data after I have selected a certain floor in my model? I'm kinda stuck here at the moment....